# How does Django rest framework verify the secondary password?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm not using `auth`, I've added a `re_password` field to my serializer, I think it only does a consistency check with the `password` field when a `POST` request comes in.

But the problem is that if `re_password` and `password` are `write_only`, then `PUT` and `PATCH` requests must also pass in these 2 fields.

I guess the consistency validation of `re_password` and `password` is reasonable for user registration, but it is not so necessary for updating user information.

What can I do to make `re_password` and `password` only required for `POST` requests?

- POST: i need `password` and `re_password` field register new user account
- PUT/PATCH: i don't need `password` and `re_password` as they are not suitable for updating user info

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    re_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, min_length=6, max_length=20, error_messages={
        "min_length": "Password at least 6 digits",
        "max_length": "Password up to 20 characters",
    })

    class Meta:
        exclude = ("is_delete",)
        model = models.User
        extra_kwargs = {**CommonSerializer.extra_kwargs, **{
            "password": {
                "write_only": True,
                "min_length": 6,
                "max_length": 20,
                "error_messages": {
                    "min_length": "Password at least 6 digits",
                    "max_length": "Password up to 20 characters",
                }
            },
        }}

    def validate_password(self, data):
        return hashlib.md5(data.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

    def validate_re_password(self, data):
        return hashlib.md5(data.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

    def validate(self, validate_data):
        if validate_data['password'] != validate_data.pop('re_password'):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("password not match")
        return validate_data

    def create(self, validate_data):
        instance = models.User.objects.create(**validate_data)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validate_data):
        password = validate_data.get("password")

        validate_data["password"] = hashlib.md5(
            password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

        for key, val in validate_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, val)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: If you are using GenericAPIView you can overwrite get_serializer_class and there you can check if request is POST or PUT and return serializer with or without password fields

Comment: Do you mean, I'm going to create multiple serializer classes?

Comment: Yes, and assign them to serializer_class based on if statement

Comment: okay, thank you. I see, this is indeed a solution.

Comment: if you are using viewset,  map partial_update function to put method. or explicilitly write in put method  serializer object like  ** serializer = YourSerializer(data=data, partial=True)  **